# Uploaded images organisation (DIR Structure) in django or any without affecting the web app speed or load time?

Tags: python, django, image, directory-structure

I'm confused about organising files and media. Let say, I have a Django website, it has over 25 models, all of them contains at least one image field. Every submitted entry in the database, create 5-6 different versions of that image by size and format. Currently, I just have a DIR for each model inside the media root which store all uploaded image related to that specific model. What is the best way to organise them in terms of loading speed. If any model or models, let say have 10,000s of entries means 50,000 to 60,000 of images as well. And when someone visits the website does it affect the speed because it is looking through so many images and putting that specifics on the user requested page? Or it doesn't matter at all?

Best way, I can keep them without putting any affecting the loading speed?:

1. Storing all images in one dir of that model (MEDIA > MODEL DIR > All Images), because it doesn't matter.
2. MEDIA > MODEL DIR > SIZES/FORMAT DIR (e.g. 200x200 or png) > All entries' images that are 200x200 in size, can have thousands of images.
3. Storing every single entry's images in a separate folder (MEDIA > MODEL DIR > ID/ENTRY NAME DIR > All images including different sizes and format, this would make 15-20 images per DIR).
4. (MEDIA > MODEL DIR > ID/ENTRY NAME DIR > SIZE/FORMAT DIR > All images of that size or format related to that entry, this would make 1 or 2 images per DIR).
5. or date/month/year wise directories? But I'm not really a fan of this one.

Also, in general what's the best way if the website is not on django?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and I use object storage with CDN.
It can be so helpful if you use this solution.

Comment: I'm quite a noob but doesn't it cost a lot?